# How to roll back an 'Inactive" transaction

Tags: java, jpa

We have a method which acts as a transaction boundary annotated with @Transactional, and it calls a method which in turn calls other methods doing some persistence.

The process needs to persist 3 entities, and when committing the transaction, the third one throws a DataIntegrityViolationException, it's expected that the transaction should be rolled back. But when checking the transaction logs, it shows that "rollback() called on an inactive transaction", and the first 2 entities have been persisted.

How should we roll back the transaction in this case?

Comment: Dont commit changes in the middleway.

Comment: We don't have commit middle way. Commit at the end, then exception was thrown, and roll back has "rollback() called on an inactive transaction".

Comment: its inactive for a reason - eg because of commiting. One bad placed @Transactional and you are full of troubles. Since there is no code, only crystal ball can help.

Comment: True it's inactive for a reason, as said in the question, due to DataIntegrityViolationException.

Comment: And why this violation could happen?? (check above). Also you can have exception somewhere in the middleway and you are swallowing it - plenty of possible reasons, 0 code. Missuse is the most probable cause as I just doubt that you have found a bug in kind of common scenario in widely used framework.